# Error:(25, 40) error: package android.support.v7.internal.view does not exist

Tags: android, android-support-library

****strong text**
I updated the support library from      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'  to         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'. I got error**

```
Error:(25, 40) error: package android.support.v7.internal.view does not exist
```

*[can anyone please tell how to resolve this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uevP.png)*

Comment: Might be some issue with alpha release. You can use the latest stable 27.0.1

Comment: using 27.0.1 it shows Error:(419, 41) error: cannot find symbol method makeRestartActivityTask(ComponentName)